# save and open picture

Tags: android, bitmap, filepath, android-sdcard

I've made a save system where I save a picture, then I close the app, and then find folder. I want to open the picture, but picture is opening very slowly. When I reset telefon samsung galaxy w, this picture opens very fast (1s). What is wrong with my code?

```
private String mImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/anppp";
private File file;

public void save()  {

    File dirPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/anppp");
    dirPath.mkdirs();
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMddHmmss");
    String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
    file = new File(mImagePath + "/"+"ProPaint-" + dateNow +".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos=null;


    try {

        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you provide a logcat of your error. We need more information to help you with your problem.

Comment: may be something to do with a big image and the thumb not created yet

Comment: 09-28 15:29:20.161: W/KeyCharacterMap(1173): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: http://shrani.si/f/3F/ht/3ujznoW/save.png

Comment: this is more informations ;) mybe it help ..

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will actually solve your problem, but you should move the `fos.close()` call to a `finally` block to make sure it executes. If some line above `fos.close()` throws an exception, the following code will be ignored and the `FileOutputStream` will remain open, giving you all kinds of troubles. When it's in the `finally` block, it executes no matter of the situation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unhandled exception type IOException fos.close(); must be at the try ;((( not at finaly..

Comment: @mamii, It should be in finally and also surrounded by the try-catch block

Comment: i cant show code how i change..;( But it stil open picture 8second i dont know what change when i reset mobile phone..

Comment: finally{
           try {
   fos.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
           
           
          }